# Viewflipper - Vertical slider

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have did slider using Viewflipper and that is from right to left mean horizontal slider we can say.
But I want to make it top(In from top) to bottom(Out to bottom) mean vertical slider.
Below is my code for horizontal sliding.

```
public static Animation inFromRightAnimation(int duration) {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        inFromRight.setDuration(duration);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }

    public static Animation outToLeftAnimation(int duration) {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );      
        outtoLeft.setDuration(duration);
        outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoLeft;
    }
```

What change I need to make it vertical(Top to bottom) sliding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Animation inFromUpAnimation(int duration) {
        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        inFromRight.setDuration(duration);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }

    public static Animation outToDownAnimation(int duration) {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f
        );      
        outtoLeft.setDuration(duration);
        outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoLeft;
    }
```

those attributes relate to x and y co-ordinates. i think this will do the job

Comment: Actually works for Up swype , from up to down isnt working :(

Comment: Just change the co ordinates and check